# Animating a dropdown advanced search

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

I'm currently making a pokedex app and have problems with animating dropdown advanced search. At the top of the viewport there is a fixed header, that contains input bar and a button responsible for displaying a block with buttons for pokemon type filtering. So I wanted to make this block sort of smoothly slide down. But I don't really know how to do this properly. Using transform: scaleY() leaves me with empty space, as it is only a visual effect and doesn't care about content. Transitioning max-height doesn't work either, because the block has height: 0, but its content is still there visible. Is there any clever way to do this? Maybe some sort of library, which can help me achieve my goal? Below are 2 views I'm talking about and want to animate between them.[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share the relevant code.

Comment: Which part of my code do you want to see? .css file or a react component? Currently there is no animation implemented, as I'm trying multiple solutions, and neither works as intended

Comment: Well, I described which steps I already took. scaleY() doesn't work. I already found out, that u can't animate height property and you have to do it with max-height. But that also doesn't work properly. I read an article at css-tricks about 3 methods for animating div height dependent on content inside. I just want to know how do I do this properly, I'm not asking about code, because I probably could code it myself. I'm only searching for an idea how to implement it. Should this block slide down from underneath a header, or maybe should it squish/unsquish somehow?